# SharePoint Online: Generating top Search queries via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search

Is it possible to access the results of a site's Popularity and Search Results via PowerShell?

Comment: You could look at the OOB reports and see if there is a way to request them. https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSearch though I am not sure how.